# Pixi js - need to make clickable background

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I need to be able to click on background, and get the position of the click.

I tried adding an event listener to stage like this

```js
app.stage.interactive = true;
app.stage.on('click', function(){
    console.log('hello');
})
```

but it works only if i click on element inside the stage, not the background itself.

Do i need to make a sprite as a background, if so, how do i set its background color and make sure it stays under all the other elements?

Answer (score 6):

The stage is a PIXI.Container, which means it's basically an empty node that can hold children.  It doesn't have dimensions of its own, and so when the interaction manager goes to hit-test your click, it isn't detected.

Your suggestion of adding a background sprite is probably the simplest solution.  You can add one like so:

```
// Create the background sprite with a basic white texture
let bg = new PIXI.Sprite(PIXI.Texture.WHITE);
// Set it to fill the screen
bg.width = app.screen.width;
bg.height = app.screen.height;
// Tint it to whatever color you want, here red
bg.tint = 0xff0000;
// Add a click handler
bg.interactive = true;
bg.on('click', function(){
  console.log('hello');
});
// Add it to the stage as the first object
app.stage.addChild(bg);

// Now add anything else you want on your stage
...
```

PixiJS renders objects in order, so if you add your background sprite as the first child of the app's stage, it will be rendered behind all other content.  When hit-testing a click, it will be the last object tested, and so will catch a click on the background of the stage.  Note that to "block" clicks, other objects will need to be set to interactive = true, even if they don't have a click handler attached!

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution would be to add an event on app's view.

```js
app.renderer.view.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  console.log(e);
});
```